# Add label tag to input without id with javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, label

How I can add a label to this input:

```
<div class="el-date-editor el-input el-input--prefix el-input--suffix el-date-editor--time-select">
 <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="" placeholder="Από" class="el-input__inner"> 
  <span class="el-input__prefix">
   <i class="el-input__icon el-icon-time"></i>
  </span>
  <span class="el-input__suffix">
   <span class="el-input__suffix-inner">
    <i class="el-input__icon"></i>
   </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

I tried this code posted in another question but didnt work. There is no ID and I dont know if its going to work with class...

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('input').wrap(function () {
        return $('<label />', {
            for: this.id
        }).append(this.previousSibling)
    })
})
```

***EDIT***

Here is the page, the elements are the 2 date fields under the calendar on the sidebar
https://skin-wellness.gr/

Comment: If you wrap an `input` in a [`label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) you do not need the `for`/`id`.

Comment: `document.querySelector(".el-input__inner").insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", "<label>Label Text</label>");`? Please let me know if it's the right answer to your question.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null

Comment: It works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ht0ovckn/

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner maybe because there are 2 inputs with same class?

Comment: No, because `querySelector` will select the first one. I don't get any error in my browser (using HTML code you posted).

Comment: Given your input sample, what is the actual output you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You could give name to input tag and get the parent of input after get it by name, then append label before the input, like:

```javascript
const input = $('input[name="required-input"]')
const parent = input.parent()

parent.prepend('<label>TEST Label</label>'))
```